# How can the source of a script be found in the inspector?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

In Google Chrome (v.72.0.3626.119) on macOS (v.10.14.3):

In the "Elements" tab, when an element (e.g., `<h2>`) is selected and then in the "Event Listeners" panel the dropdown for an event (e.g., `click`) is activated, it lists the target (i.e., the `<h2>`) and usually the file name and line number (e.g., `index.js:12`). When I hover over the file name, it reveals the path to the file (e.g., `http://example.com/index.js:12`).

However, sometimes it does not display the file name, but instead something like `VM1234:56`. When hovered, it displays something like `debugger:///VM1234:56`.

How can I find the actual source of this script?

Comment: Can you provide an example on [Glitch](https://glitch.com) where you're seeing this behavior?

Comment: Hi, @KayceBasques: I can't find this behaviour on Glitch. It looks like all the event listeners are neatly contained to an index.js file. I'll try to find an example and post it.